# PHP date manipulation applying TZOFFSETFROM & TZOFFSETTO values?

Tags: php, datetime, calendar, icalendar

I am trying to parse a google calendar and I realise that I need to apply daylight saving time to the event times, otherwise they are displayed incorrectly (in this case an hour out).

I realise I can read TZOFFSETFROM & TZOFFSETTO from the calendar and I can use date( 'I', $date ) to determine whether the selected date is affected by Daylight Savings time.

However, the value that comes from TZOFFSETFROM / TO is in the format +0100 and I am curious to know what the best way to apply this to my time value is.

Should I break this time down into sign / hour / min and then use that information to change my hour and minute times or is there a more pragmatic way to do this math? I really don't like the idea of breaking the string down, it seems too likely to result in an error.

ALSO
Is it safe to only use TZOFFSETTO (assuming the google calendar and my server are working in the same timezone) or should I do a more extended calculation based on the difference between TZOFFSETFROM and TZOFFSETTO?

Any advice would be very welcome. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Robin,

safest way would be to use the php datetime object.
http://php.net/manual/en/book.datetime.php

Create the dates in the timezone that google has specified they are in.

To shift timezone http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.settimezone.php

No need to worry about daylight saving as php will handle that for you.
You just have to be very clear about which timezone you should be in at what time.